# My wifi won't let me access my own domain (hard reset works for a bit)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, static-ip

I'm desperate.

It seems that my router doesn't have access to my own website and all related stuff.

Here's what I have:

- I have a website and a smartphone app, all under the same domain (the app on the sub).
- If I connect using my phone network or some other wifi (public, friend's house, office...), things work fine.
- If I use my home wifi, no matter the device, it just won't work. This is also valid for other people (if they use their own network, all good; if they use my home wifi, it won't load).
- If I use VPN, it works fine even from my home wifi.
- A hard reset of the router will make things work for a bit, even a dozen minutes, and then... poof, it stops again. But if I activate VPN on my broswer, it works again.

Given this, I assume it has something to do with my router's dynamic IP (if I'm not mistaken VPNs use a static IP?), although I'm not even sure what this means...

Additional info — althgouh some of this might be inexact because I can't be 100% sure of the timing at which things were being done by my hosting provider:

- I'm on a dedicated server (checked with yougetsignal.com).
- My hosting provider has tried moving all of my stuff on a different server and things seemed to work fine there, but now it doesn't work.

I can't be sure if I'm now on a server different from the one I was on when I started experiencing these problems, but I think I am because the IP I see now on my cPanel is different from the previous one.

My developer/hosting service (same company) doesn't seem to be able to solve this. Super User, halp!!

Desperately,

Mu

Comment: Did you prototype this site on your own LAN? Did you maybe set up something like a local DNS record on your router that points your domain name to the internal LAN host you prototyped it on?

Comment: Does your domain at least *resolve to the correct IP address* when the problem starts occurring?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses.
I wasn't able to understand your answers/troubleshooting, maybe it would have helped me solve it faster but...
I don't know what the opposite of a super user is (a super Luser?), but that's me.

Luckily I managed to solve it, so I'll leave the solution here for future reference in case someone has the same problem.

So, it was all in the communication between my email client and the email provider.

The email addresses I have under the domain are in cPanel.
After migrating everything onto the new server, all passwords were reset, or rather deleted so my emails had no passwords. When my email client tried to fetch new emails, it caused some super conflict that caused my router to be blocked (guessing), although not at server level.
No idea how this works, but actually my clients (phone as well) had warned me for days that the passwords didn't work anymore. I was so focused on trying to solve things on IP/server level with the developers, that I procrastinated this task. Well, it was exactly what caused the problem.

All I did was go to cPanel, re-enter all my email passwords, and all of a sudden all the problems were solved. My client also fetched ALL messages I had sent in the mean time testing things.

Hope this will give a hand to anyone who ends up in a similar scenario. Even my developer didn't think of this.

Cheers, and thanks again!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).